# Creating a link_to action for will_paginate + order_by parameters (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a parameter in my comments called `total_votes` (composed of integers).
This is how I order comments by the most voted and apply will paginate at the same time:

**show.rb:**

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                        :per_page => 5).order('total_votes DESC,
                                                               created_at DESC')
  end
```

**show.html.erb:**

```
<% @comments.map do |comment| %>
  <div class="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Vote:</b>
    <span class="vote-count"><%= comment.total_votes %></span>

    <div class='voted-user'>
      <% comment.votes.each do |vote| %>
        <%= link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Commenter</b>
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Link</b>
    <%= link_to "Show Post Comment", [@post, comment] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Vote</b>
    <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(comment, :votable_type => "Comment"), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %><br />
  </p>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @comments %>
```

I would like to create a `link_to` action so that I can manipulate this part:

```
@comments = @post.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                    :per_page => 5).order('THIS_PART')
```

So that I can archive something like this:

> mysite/posts/93?order_by=votes

and or this (order_by + will_paginate):

> mysite/posts/93?order_by=votes&page=2

or something like that.

Any suggestions about how to accomplish code this in the controller and view (Please let me know if this is not the best way of doing it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) is what you want!

Comment: thanks but I also need how to code that in the controller and view.